# Cordova 5.3.3 cordovalib.jar not exist

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I have installed  Cordova 5.3.3 and created android project when i run the project with eclipse it show me these errors as in the image.
http://s3.postimg.org/ebf0f0gg3/image.png
i searched in the project/libs to find the cordovalib.jar and found it empty

Answer (score 1):

@user2239044, without announcement Cordova moved the repository server. Reset your environment, download the latest version. That likely won't be enough. When you rebuild your app, you'll need to

- set the version for your compiler
- set the version for your plugins
- set the source for your plugins to NPM

That still won't be enought, because there are no enough details about your app in the post. But start right there, and report the errors you get.

And for God's sake learn to use cut and paste, and don't be lazy with a screen shot.